# How to scale image?

Tags: iphone, image-scaling

How to scale image with goo quality. I am using this following code but when I am taking  using image from Camera its showing in different frame.

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image {
int w = image.size.width;
int h = image.size.height; 

CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

int width, height;

int destWidth = 640;
int destHeight = 480;
if(w > h){
    width = destWidth;
    height = h*destWidth/w;
} else {
    height = destHeight;
    width = w*destHeight/h;
}

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef bitmap;
bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, M_PI/2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -height);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI/2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -width, 0);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, width,height);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI);

}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;  
}
```

If there is anyway to reduce size without affecting to quality please suggest
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce size, you will have to compromise on the resolution of the image. I suggest you calculate a new WIDTH and HEIGHT for the image.

Here is something that worked for me:

Try this:

```
-(UIImage*) resizeImage:(CGImageRef)image toWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height
{
// create context, keeping original image properties
  CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image);
  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height,                                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image),                                           CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                             colorspace,
                                             CGImageGetAlphaInfo(image));

       if(context == NULL)
       {
        NSLog(@"Could not re-size");
        return nil; 
       }
      // draw image to context (resizing it)
      CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
      // extract resulting image from context
      CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
      CGContextRelease(context);
      UIImage* resizedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
      CGImageRelease(imgRef);
      return resizedImage;  
}
```

Comment: Note that this would not work when the alpha info is not supported or there is some other bitmap info necessary. You should mask out the alpha bits, then set it to kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code for scale the image for camera image. please implement if you found help ful

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
                didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                                    editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

//// ADDIGN THIS LINE WHEN YOU CAPTURED IMAGE 

    image = [self scaleAndRotateImage:image];
    [self useImage:image];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

/// THE METHODS ROTATE THE CURRENT CAPTURED IMAGE AT 90 DEGREE OF ANGLE

- (void)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    int kMaxResolution = 320; // Or whatever

    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setRotatedImage:imageCopy];
    //return imageCopy;
}
```